# Python counting zeros

Tags: python, loops, count, zero

I have created a code which basically generates a random 20 digit number. Code below:

```
import random
from random import randint

n=20

def digit(n):

    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end+1)


print(digit(n))
```

The output of this code for example is:

```
49690101904335902069
```

Now given this code I'm just wondering how I can go about to counting the number of zeros in the output, so essentially I'm trying to create a new function called `count_zero():`, but I have no idea what to put it for my parameter and what not.

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in your digit generation; use `range_end` in randint(); the end value is *inclusive*.

Answer (score 14):

Turn the number into a string and count the number of `'0'` characters:

```
def count_zeros(number):
    return str(number).count('0')
```

Demo:

```
>>> def count_zeros(number):
...     return str(number).count('0')
... 
>>> count_zeros(49690101904335902069)
5
```

Or without turning it into a string:

```
def count_zeros(number):
    count = 0
    while number > 9:
        count += int(number % 10 == 0)
        number //= 10
    return count
```

The latter approach is a *lot* slower however:

```
>>> import random
>>> import timeit
>>> test_numbers = [random.randrange(10 ** 6) for _ in xrange(1000)]
>>> def count_zeros_str(number):
...     return str(number).count('0')
... 
>>> def count_zeros_division(number):
...     count = 0
...     while number > 9:
...         count += int(number % 10 == 0)
...         number //= 10
...     return count
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('[c(n) for n in test_numbers]',
...     'from __main__ import test_numbers, count_zeros_str as c', number=5000)
2.4459421634674072
>>> timeit.timeit('[c(n) for n in test_numbers]',
...     'from __main__ import test_numbers, count_zeros_division as c', number=5000)
7.91981315612793
```

To combine this with your code, just add the function, and *call* it separately; you can pass in the result of `digit()` directly or store the result first, then pass it in:

```
print(count_zeros(digit(n)))
```

or separately (which allows you to show the resulting random number too):

```
result = digit(n)
zeros = count_zeros(result)
print('result', result, 'contains', zeros, 'zeros.')
```

Comment: any way of doing it without converting to a string? `from itertools import Counter` doesnt work

Comment: @letsc: nothing *faster*, no.

Comment: just wanted to clarify, what is the number argument that you put inside the function?

Comment: @Giovanni: the number in which you wanted to count the zeros.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I made an edit above to my code, i tried to incorporate what you designed but to no avail

Comment: @Giovanni: you put the function call to `digit(n)` into the function definition of `count_zeros`. Copy my code *entirely*, you misunderstood how function arguments work.

Comment: @Giovanni: on a *separate* line, use `print(count_zeros(digit(n)))`

Comment: Just ran it with that verbatim, and got this as the two outputs: 36508688671526092966 (random number) and 3 zeros.... I only see two zeros in that output so I'm guessing there must be a mistake somewhere

Comment: @Giovanni: Did you generate a *new* number or did you use the `36508688671526092966` value? Because `count_zeros(36508688671526092966)` gives 2, not 3.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I used the 36508688671526092966  value, I just ran it again and this time my output was 93266744360084724735 and it said there was only 1 zero..

Comment: @Giovanni: I cannot reproduce that using the code in my answer. Try it with *just* those numbers, so `count_zeros(36508688671526092966)` and `count_zeros(93266744360084724735)`.

Comment: @Giovanni: do **not** use `print(digits(n))` then `print(count_zeros(digits(n)))` because then you generate **two separate values** and the output of those two print statements is not related in any way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good catch, just realized that it may generate two diff numbers lol..